# Why are transformers abbreviated XFMR?

Tags: transformer

The "FMR" is intuitive; short for "former."

But how do we get "Trans" from "X"?  Is there some reason "X" was used specifically?

I can't recall seeing any labeled TF, TFMR, or TRFMR, although those all seem lexicographically more correct than XFMR.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/541226/why-is-the-prefix-trans-shortened-to-x

Comment: The same way you get Xmas out of Christmas, if you can shorten it, it will be shortend

Comment: Hint. "trans" means "across".

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37394/why-do-some-words-have-x-as-a-substitute

Comment: It’s an abbreviation that uses homologous symbols

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word "transformer" is derived from "[trans](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trans#Latin)" meaning "across". "Across" can be simplified further to "cross". We now a have a literal cross, using the shorthand X.

XTAL is another abbreviation by same logic, used for crystals.

Comment: Ironic, that XFMR = "trans"former, while XTAL = "cryst"al.  Wonder if anyone has ever read that as "cross-tal."